# opencv java program slow execution

Tags: java, arrays, performance, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a program to track motion of the eyeball using opencv java library.This is my algo--

1. initially store pixels of open eyeball(original image)
2. detect eyeball (in next image) using haarcascade classifier
3. count no. of white pixels and compare with original image to find if eye is closed
4. if not closed, convert mat to byte array
5. extract r,g,b values for each pixel from array and process to find the relative position of eyeball with respect to original image
6. the processing involves counting no. of white pixels to left and right of eyeball
7. if (left px >right px) eyeball is right and vice versa.

But the execution is very slow .Loading the image to Mat from disk takes 100ms and the processing takes 600ms for each image. This is my code --

```
    package sumit;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs; // imread, imwrite, etc
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;


public class FaceDetector  {
    static MatOfRect faceDetections;
    static Mat image,full,face;
    static char yyy;
    static int gh,lop;
    static boolean d=false;
    static int width,height,white1,white2,white5,white6,
    w1,w2,h1,h2;
    static int left5;
    static int[] buf1,buf2;
    static CascadeClassifier faceDetector2;
    static MatOfRect faceDetections7;
    static double xl,xr,xle,xre,yl,yr,yle,yre;
    static int[] xyz;
    static byte[] byby,byby1,byby2,byby3;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        faceDetector2= new CascadeClassifier();
        faceDetections7 = new MatOfRect();
        int cal=0;



        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture();
        while(true)

        {
            if(!camera.isOpened()){


                full = Imgcodecs.imread("sumit/sumit20 (3).jpg");
                if(cal==1)full = Imgcodecs.imread("sumit/sumit55.jpg");

            }

            else {
                camera.read(full);
            }

            if(cal==0)
            {

                cal=1;
                headpose0();
            }
            else 
                {
                    headpose1();

                }
                //System.out.println(String.format("%s",toString(endTime - startTime)));

        }   

    }


    static int close(){
        int xmx=0,xms=0;
        Rect jio[]=faceDetections7.toArray();
        for(int i=0;i<jio.length;i++)
        {
            if(jio[i].height>xms)
            {
                xmx=i;
                xms=jio[i].height;
            }
        }
        return xmx;
    }


    static void headpose0(){

        faceDetector2.load("D:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        faceDetector2.detectMultiScale(full, faceDetections7);

        if(faceDetections7.toArray().length>1)
        {
            face=new Mat(full,faceDetections7.toArray()[close()]);

        }
        else
        {
            face=new Mat(full,faceDetections7.toArray()[0]);

        }
        int face_width=face.width();
        int face_height=face.height();
        //Mat lefti=(yy=='l')?new Mat(image,faceDetections.toArray()[left5]):new Mat(image,faceDetections.toArray()[1-left5]);

        faceDetector2.load("D:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml");

        faceDetector2.detectMultiScale(face, faceDetections7);
        int xmx=0,xms=0,xms1=0,xmx1=1;
        Rect jio1[]=faceDetections7.toArray();

        if(jio1.length>2)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<jio1.length;i++)
            {
                if(jio1[i].height>xms)
                {
                    xmx=i;
                    xms=jio1[i].height;
                }

                else if(jio1[i].height>xms1)

                {
                    xmx1=i;
                    xms1=jio1[i].height;
                }
            }
        }

        int left=(jio1[xmx].x<jio1[xmx1].x)?xmx:xmx1;
        int right=(left==xmx)?xmx1:xmx;

        xl=((double)(jio1[left].x) )/((double) face_width);
        xr=((double)(jio1[right].x)) / ((double) face_width);
        xle=((double)(jio1[left].x+jio1[left].width) ) / ((double)face_width);
        xre=((double)(jio1[right].x+jio1[right].width) )/((double) face_width);
        yl=((double)jio1[left].y  )/ ((double) face_height);
        yr=((double)jio1[right].y ) /  ((double)face_height);
        yle=((double)(jio1[left].y+jio1[left].height) )/ ((double)face_height);
        yre=((double)(jio1[right].y+jio1[right].height)  )/((double) face_height);

        Mat sy=new Mat(face,jio1[left]);
        Mat sys=new Mat(face,jio1[right]);

        buf1=buf(sy);           
        white1=white(buf1,1);
        buf2=buf(sys);
        white2=white(buf2,1);
        System.out.println(white1 +"\t"+white2 );

        if(lop==0)
        {
            lop=1;
            xyx.main1(buf1,sy.width(),sys.height());

        }

    }



    static void headpose1(){

        faceDetector2.load("D:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

        faceDetector2.detectMultiScale(full, faceDetections7);

        if(faceDetections7.toArray().length>1)
        {
            face=new Mat(full,faceDetections7.toArray()[close()]);

        }
        else
        {
            face=new Mat(full,faceDetections7.toArray()[0]);

        }
        int face_width=face.width();
        int face_height=face.height();
        //Mat lefti=(yy=='l')?new Mat(image,faceDetections.toArray()[left5]):new Mat(image,faceDetections.toArray()[1-left5]);

        Mat cf=face.submat((int)(yl*face_height), (int)(yle*face_height), 
                (int)(xl*face_width),(int)( xle*face_width)  ) ;
        Mat cd=face.submat((int)(yr*face_height), (int)(yre*face_height), 
                (int)(xr*face_width),(int)( xre*face_width)  );

        buf1=buf(cf );
        w1 =cf.width();
        w2=cd.width();
        h1 =cf.height();
        h2=cd.height();

        buf2=buf( cd );


        white5=white(buf1,5);
        white6=white(buf2,1);

        System.out.println(white5 +"\t"+white6 );
        if(!blink())
            lefte('l');


    }

    //extract eye from image(yy=1(left) =0(right)
    static  void lefte(char yy) 
    {   
        yyy=yy;


        if(yy=='l')
        {
            xyz=buf1;
            width=w1;
            height = h1;
        }
        else if(yy=='r')
        {

            xyz=buf2;
            color(xyz);
            width=w2;
            height = h2;
        }


        joi();
        int at=t1();
        if(at==3)lefte('r');
        else 
        {
            xyx.main1(xyz,width,height);
            line();
        }
    }


    //converts mat to buffered image
    static int[] buf(Mat image){
        int index=0;
        byte[] data = new byte[image.rows()*image.cols()*(int)(image.elemSize())];
        int[] datax=new int [image.rows()*image.cols()*(int)(image.elemSize())];
        image.get(0, 0, data);

        for(int x:data){
            datax[index]=x & 0xFF;
            index++;
        }


        return datax;
    }



    //draws line where  max red and blue >width/6
    static void line(){
        int limit0=(width*gh);
        int limit1=(width*(gh-1));
        for(int j=limit0;j<limit1;j++)
        {
            xyz[j+2]=0;
            xyz[j+1]=255;
            xyz[j]=0;
        }       

    }

    static int  white(int[] buf1,int ert){
        int ans=0;int max,min;
        for(int j=0;j<buf1.length;j+=3)
        {

             max=Math.max  (buf1[j], Math.max(buf1[j+1],buf1[j+2] ) );
             min=Math.min  (buf1[j], Math.min(buf1[j+1],buf1[j+2] ) );

            if(min>110 && (max-min)<20 ){
                if(ert==5)
                { 

                    buf1[j+2]=255;
                    buf1[j+1]=0;
                    buf1[j]=0;
                }
                ans++;
            }
            else if(ert==5){

                if(min>80 && (max-min)<20 ){

                    buf1[j+2]=255;
                    buf1[j+1]=0;
                    buf1[j]=0;
                }   

                else if(min<70 && (max-min)<20 )
                {
                    buf1[j+2]=0;
                    buf1[j+1]=0;
                    buf1[j]=255;
                }       
            }

        }

        return ans;

    }

    static void color(int[] tab){
        int max;
        int min;

        for(int j=0;j<tab.length;j+=3)
        {

             max=Math.max  (tab[j], Math.max(tab[j+1],tab[j+2] ) );
             min=Math.min  (tab[j], Math.min(tab[j+1],tab[j+2] ) );

            if(min>80 && (max-min)<20 ){

                tab[j+2]=255;
                tab[j+1]=0;
                tab[j]=0;
            }   

            else if(min<70 && (max-min)<20 )
            {
                tab[j+2]=0;
                tab[j+1]=0;
                tab[j]=255;
            }       

        }
    }


    static boolean  blink(){

        boolean xdx=false;
        if ( (white5<(white1*0.6 ) ) && (  white6 < (white2*0.6)) )
        {
            System.out.println("bb");
            // Serial(bb)
            xdx=true;

        }

        else if (white5 < (white1*0.6) )
        {
            System.out.println("lb");
            // Serial(lb)
            xdx=true;

        }

        else if (white6 < (white2*0.6)  )
        {
            System.out.println("rb");
            // Serial(rb)
            xdx=true;

        }
        return xdx;

    }


    //finds pos of eyeball
    static int  t1(){
        int a1=0,a4=0,a3=0,a5=0,a6=0,a7=0;
        int limit0=(width*gh);
        int limit1=(width*(gh-1));

        for (int i=limit0; i<limit1;i+=3)
        {
            if(xyz[i+2]==255 && xyz[i+1]==0  && xyz[i]==0)
            {
                a1++;
                if(a3==0)
                {
                    a3=1;
                    a6=i;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (a1>a5)
                {
                    a5=a1;
                    a7=i-1;
                    a4=a6;
                }

                a3=0;
                a1=0;
            }
        }


        int ix=0,bx=0;boolean left=false;

        for(int i=(limit0+(a4*3));i>limit0;i-=3)
        {

            if(xyz[i]==255 && xyz[i+1]==0  && xyz[i+2]==0)
            {
                ix++;
            }
        }


        for(int i=(limit0+(a7*3));i<limit1;i+=3)
        {
            if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
            {
                bx++;
            }

        }

        left = (ix>bx)?true:false;


        String omi=null;
        int l1,l2,l5,l6;
        l1=l2=l5=l6=0;
        int x1,x2,x4,x5,x6,x8;
        x1=x2=x4=x5=x6=x8=0;

        if(!left)
        {

            for(int i=(limit0+(a7*3));i<limit1;i+=3)

            {


                if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                {
                    l1++;
                }
                if(xyz[i]==0 && xyz[i+2]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                {if(l1> (width/6.0) )
                    l2++;
                }
            }

            if(l2< (width*0.05)  )omi="right";
            //  if(l2>width/)
            //  if (a7<width*(3.5/8.0)) omi="centre";
            //if (a7>=width/2.0) omi="right";

            else
            {
                sumit1:
                    for (int i=(limit0+(a7*3));i<limit1;i+=3)
                    {
                        if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                        {
                            x5++;
                        }

                        if(x5 >width*(1.0/15.0)  )

                        {
                            if(xyz[i]==0 && xyz[i+2]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                            {
                                x1++;
                                x2=0;
                                if(x1> width*(1.0/60.0) )
                                {
                                    x6=3;
                                    x8=10;                      

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                x2++;

                                if(x2> width*(1.0/18.0) )
                                {
                                    if(x6==3)break sumit1;
                                    x1=0;
                                }

                                if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                                {
                                    if(x8!=10)  x8=7;
                                    x4=0;   
                                }

                                else
                                {

                                    if(x8==7)  x4++;
                                    if(x4> width*(1.0/15.0) ) break sumit1;

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (x1>  width*0.05) omi="centre";
                        if (x1<  width*0.05 ) omi="right";

                    }
            }
        }



        if(left)
        {
            if(yyy=='l')return 3;

            for(int i=(limit0+(a4*3));i>limit0;i-=3)

            {
                if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                {
                    l5++;
                }

                if(xyz[i]==0 && xyz[i+2]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                {if(l5> (width/6.0) )
                    l6++;
                }
            }

            if(l6< (width*0.05)  )omi="left";

            //  if(l2>width/)
            //  if (a7<width*(3.5/8.0)) omi="centre";
            //if (a7>=width/2.0) omi="right";

            else
            {
                x1=x2=x4=x5=x6=x8=0;
                sumit:

                    for (int i=(limit0+(a7*3));i<limit1;i+=3)
                    {
                        if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                        {
                            x5++;
                        }

                        if(x5 >width*(1.0/15.0) )

                        {
                            if(xyz[i]==0 && xyz[i+2]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                            {
                                x1++;
                                x2=0;
                                if(x1> width*(1.0/60.0) )
                                {
                                    x6=3;
                                    x8=10;                      

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                x2++;

                                if(x2>  width*(1.0/18.0) )
                                {
                                    if(x6==3)break sumit;
                                    x1=0;
                                }

                                if(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0)
                                {
                                    if(x8!=10)  x8=7;
                                    x4=0;   
                                }

                                if(!(xyz[i+2]==0 && xyz[i]==255  && xyz[i+1]==0))
                                {

                                    if(x8==7)  x4++;
                                    if(x4>width*(1.0/15.0)  ) break sumit;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (x1> width*0.05 )omi="centre";
                        if (x1< width*0.05 )omi="right";

                    }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(omi);
        return 0;

    }


    //calculates line with max red and blue >width/6
    static void joi(){
        System.out.println(width/6);

        int ko=0,koi=0,max=0,row=0,col=0;



        for(int j=0;j<xyz.length;j+=3)
        {

            if(xyz[j+2]==255 && xyz[j+1]==0  && xyz[j]==0)
                ko++;

            else if(xyz[j+2]==0 && xyz[j+1]==0  && xyz[j]==255)
                koi++;

            col++;
            if(col==width){

                //System.out.println(koi);
                if(ko>max && koi > width/6.0)
                {
                    max=ko;
                    gh=row;
                }
                row++;
                ko=0;koi=0;
            }

        }   

    }    

}
```

How can I increase my program speed? also, which is faster --

1. extract each pixels from mat and process
2. convert mat to byte[] and extract r,g,b values from byte[] and process

1 last question - Does the Mat.get(0,0,byte[]) store pixels(in the byte[]) in r,g,b or b,g,r order ?

Comment: for 2. `byte[]` should be way faster as it does not wrap around the data, while `mat` adds wrappers around the data, for last question i'm not sure it depends on endianess but i would say `r,g,b` is the order (it should be normalised)

Comment: a passing note i think that the way to detect the eyeball position is slow in itself, better think of some alternative in order to process fewer pixels, for example no need to count both left and right pixels (assume that left/right have equal amount of pixels and compute only one side) there can be other optimisations as well

Comment: another optimisation is that closed eye detection can again be done with fewer pixels (exploit eye symmetries and knowledge to speed-up the process)., for exampe sample the eyeball at specific locations only and detect closed or not from only those few pixels and so on

Comment: but for different images ,the eye is at different position and the line of symmetry keeps changing

Comment: that is why first you use an eye detector to get the eye position and then do the rest operatins only inside that area, so this is not a problem (have made similar scheme for a make-up application for face/eyes/cheecks using computer vision algorithms and haar detectors)

Comment: also try to cache some computed values instead of computing them again on next step of the process (provided they are the same), this can be a big speed-up